# Mui DatePicker change icon position

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui, icons

Im trying to customize  mui DatePicker  I was able to change the icon but not its position
I want the icon to be in the beginning before the text and not in the end as the image shows here is my code

```
 <ThemeProvider theme={calendarTheme}>
        <DatePicker
          disabled={false}
          leftArrowButtonText={t("notification.previous_month")}
          rightArrowButtonText={t("notification.next_month")}
          minDate={today}
          InputProps={{
            classes: { notchedOutline: classes.noBorder },
        
          }}
          components={{
            OpenPickerIcon: Table,
            SwitchViewIcon: ArrowDown,
          }}
          value={value}
          onChange={handlechange}
          renderInput={(params: any) => (
            <TextField
              style={{
                color: "red",
              }}
              {...params}
            />
          )}
        />
      </ThemeProvider>
```

[image: the icon current position]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set a class to `DatePicker` which has following style:

```
const styles = {
  root: {
    "flex-direction": "row-reverse"
  }
};
```

Then add it to `DatePicker`:

```
<DatePicker
            keyboard
            placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"
            format={"MM/DD/YYYY"}
            InputProps={{
              classes: { root: classes.root }
            }}
            value={this.state.selectedDate}
            onChange={this.handleDateChange}
            disableOpenOnEnter
            animateYearScrolling={false}
            autoOk={true}
            clearable
            onInputChange={(e) => console.log("Keyboard:", e.target.value)}
          />
```

[image: Edit Material UI Date Picker (forked)]